# Compiling error in Vs code while coding in C

Tags: c, mingw

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a: error adding symbols: No more archived files
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i countered this error while compiling my C code in VS code
please consider helping me

Comment: Why the GCC tag if you're using MINGW?